# How to get two number from a string and convert to int in one variable?

Tags: c, logic

I'm trying to finish up my homework and this is the last thing I couldn't figure it out since this afternoon.

Say for example I have string in the array like this `ABCD24EFG` and I want to get that number `24` in a variable that I initialize which type is `int`

I can do it with one single number and convert it like this

```
number_holder = array_name[4] - '0';
```

and I will get `2` in the `number_holder` but how can I get the whole like `24` and convert them into `int` type?

Comment: If you can find one number in a string, have you tried looking ahead to the next position in the string and checking to see if that is a number too?

Comment: @Eric I have if statement to perform the check if is a number or not.

Comment: Replace 4 with a running index from a for-loop. Btw.: Every variable is a form of holder, so naming one of them _holder doesn't help much. The same is true for 'array_', which only hinders refactoring, if you happen to favor a vector for instance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get to number from an array and assign to one int](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10640288/get-to-number-from-an-array-and-assign-to-one-int)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this logic.

```
number_holder=array_name[4] - '0';
number_holder=number_holder*10 + (array_name[5] - '0');
```

This way you can also handle array values like ABCD243EFG, ABCD2433EFG ...

ASCII value for integers 0-9 are 48 - 57 ..So use this for finding integers in array.

```
   number_holder=0;
   For (int i=0;i<arraylength;i++) 
    {
        if(array[i]<58 && array[i]>47)
        number_holder=number_holder*10+array[i] - '0';
    }
```

You will have your result in number_holder.

Comment: @vikiiii: It will work for more digits as long as you remember each additional digit goes from ones, to tens, to hundreds, etc.

Comment: @spyke I'm getting segmentation fault not sure why, but still figuring it out.... :(

Comment: @Ali: For segmentation faults double check your array indexes. You might be reading/writing outside your arrays.

Comment: Okay I fixed the segmentation fault, but I'm kinda confuse of your for loop what is the purpose of that?

Comment: @Ali:Just delimit iteration with your array size.

Comment: @spyke oh just notice you are trying to make it like how to get the number in the array using for loop right?

Comment: @spyke I tested, but still not actually giving the right answer :(

Comment: If you replace the magic numbers by `>= '0'` and `<= '9'`, the code is more self documenting.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the famous algorithm

```
n = 0
while (char = nextchar()) {
  n = n*10 + digit(char)
}
```

in pseudo language

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
    number_holder_1 = array_name[4] - '0';
    number_holder_2 = array_name[5] - '0';
```

You will get both number.
And perform

```
number = number_holder_1  * 10 + number_holder_2 ;
```

If the number must not be 2 digits , then you can use a for loop to get the required number.