# Get to number from an array and assign to one int

Tags: c, logic

I'm working on my homework and trying to get two characters which are numbers from an array for example `ABC10DEF`

I want to get `10` and store it in an `int` type.

```
            number_holder_1 = back[3] - '0';
            number_holder_2 = back[4] - '0';

            number = number_holder_1 * 10 + number_holder_2;
```

This doesn't work I don't know why.

When I print out the value of `number_holder_1` it does display `1` and when I display `number_holder_2` it display `0` but when I print `number` it just display `0`

I don't know how.

UPDATE:

The `number`, `number_holder_1` and `number_holder_2` are define as `int` type.

the array called `back` that holding `ABC10DEF` is passing from the main.

Comment: `number` is declared as `int` ?

Comment: @Radu it just not for displaying I'm trying to store it to `int` and use it in `for loop`

Comment: and `number_holder_1` and `number_holder_2` are `int`s as well? If so, I don't see why it would give wrong result for `number`.

Comment: What is the line of the print statement you are using to output `number`?  Note that it's easiest to help if you give a self-contained example that people can compile to reproduce your issue...then we won't have to ask all these guesswork questions!  Read this: http://sscce.org/

Comment: @HostileFork I'm going to update with more information sorry.

Comment: [It seems to work](http://ideone.com/ZxF5e)

Comment: @Ali Info is still not enough.

Comment: Duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10629612/how-to-get-two-number-from-a-string-and-convert-to-int-in-one-variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears to be an implementation mistake, because using what you have given, with some better variable names, it does work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int letter2int(char c) {
    int n;
    if (isdigit(c)) {
        n = c - '0';
    } else {
        n = -1; /* error */
    }

    /* for debugging */
    printf("For character '%c' we get number '%d'.\n", c, n);

    return n;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    const char str[] = "ABC10DEF";
    int tens, ones;
    int result;

    tens = letter2int(str[3]);
    ones = letter2int(str[4]);

    result = tens * 10 + ones;

    printf("Result: %d\n", result);

    return 0;
}
```

This can be generalized to either form a atoi function (ASCII to integer) or extract the first number that occurs in a string (terminated by any non-digit character) by using a loop and a `char` pointer to index over the string `str`.

Using `i` as the zero-based index, `result += number * (int)pow(10, i);`.

Comment: @myctylr, I'm not allow to create like a new function, but I'm going to see what can I change from what you have gave.

Comment: @Ali, I suggest you are going to look for the bug in your own code by comparing the two.

Comment: I promise I'm not going to use your code. I'm going to first look where is really a mistake.